# Error: You need to pass auth instance to use gRPC-fallback client in browser or other non-Node.js environments

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-vision

I'm trying to set google application credentials using the following command `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=KEY_PATH`(I replaced KEY_PATH with the path of the JSON file that contains my service account key).

When I run this command

`gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` everything works fine.

But I get this error on the browser

> Error: {"servicePath":"vision.googleapis.com","port":443,"clientConfig":{},"fallback":true}You need to pass auth instance to use gRPC-fallback client in browser or other non-Node.js environments. Use OAuth2Client from google-auth-library.

This is the file where I use vision:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
      
      const Home = () => {
          // Get a reference to the Cloud Vision API component
const Vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const vision = new Vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

        const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);
        const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = React.useState(null);
      
        const capture = React.useCallback(() => {
          const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();

          let text;
    vision.textDetection(imageSrc)
        .then(([detections]) => {
            const annotation = detections.textAnnotations[0];
            text = annotation ? annotation.description : '';
            console.log(`Extracted text: ${text}`);
            console.log(`Extracted text from image (${text.length} chars)`);
        }).catch(vis_err => {
            console.error("Vision error:" , vis_err);
        });
          setImgSrc(imageSrc);
        }, [webcamRef, setImgSrc]);
      
        return (
            <>
              <Webcam
                audio={false}
                ref={webcamRef}
                screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
              />
              <button onClick={capture}>Capture photo</button>
              {imgSrc && (
                <img
                  src={imgSrc}
                />
              )}
            </>
          );
        };
export default Home
```

Could anyone explain why this is happening and how it could be solved? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tired? keyFilename: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for your response. If I write: keyFilename:  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS I get the error: google_application_credentials is not defined. If I add the apostrophe around, I get the same error as before, just with the changed keyFilename.

Comment: @DaImTo I have made an edit to the post. I was able to solve the google applications credentials by writting a different path, but the error on the browser persists. Could it be a problem that React.js is causing?

Comment: Does your SA have proper permissions to use vision? Which roles did you assigned to this SA? Could you provide all your steps to replicate this issue? if you will execute `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` are you getting your path?

Comment: The SA should have proper permission, since it works in other projects. The assigned role is owner. Executing the command you provided returns: $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the cmd. I followed all steps in this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/setup#windows. When setting up the project I also used the command firebase init, so I have a few other files, such as firestore.rules etc. I made an edit to the post and added the code, where I use the vision API.

Comment: @PjoterS I also created basic node.js script with the same key, which works. But with a simple npx create-react-app command (React without the firebase init command) I get the error mentioned above. It seems that React is the issue.

Comment: @Nina

We're in the end of 2023 and Google still doesn't provide a way to use some services from the browser. 

Anyways, did you find the solution to make this work. I'm using Google Speech to text and getting the same error. Even after using the OAuth2Client, I'm getting some errors. 

If you've made it work, could you please share some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was closed on Github a while back:

> this library is supposed to be used from a server-side Node.js application, not from any front-end environment such as a browser, Electron app, React, (name your front-end framework here). If you just run the code by plain regular Node.js, it will work.Having said that - we do have experimental support for a browser use case starting from the latest version, which is 0.11.0. It's experimental (just implemented) and not really documented yet. You can try using it though. To do that, you need to pass an authenticated instance of OAuth2Client (from google-auth-library) as an auth parameter of the client constructor

Here is the link: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/issues/405#issuecomment-529713296